# how to format / convert datetime to ISO8601 in Firebird DB?

Tags: firebird, iso8601

How can I format a datetime to ISO 8601?

To my knowledge there is no built-in function in Firebird DB to format a date or timestamp as `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffff` (ISO8601 standard representation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebird has no built-in function to do this. And a cast to string will always apply a locale specific formatting. The best way to do it right now is to not do it in the database at all, but to leave this to presentation layer in your application.

If however you really need it in the database, then a stable way is:

```sql
extract(year from ts) || 
'-' || lpad(extract(month from ts), 2, '0') || 
'-' || lpad(extract(day from ts), 2, '0') || 
'T' || lpad(extract(hour from ts), 2, '0') || 
':' || lpad(extract(minute from ts), 2, '0') || 
':' || lpad(extract(second from ts), 2, '0')
```

If you are using Firebird 3, then you can wrap this in your own function:

```sql
create function iso8601timestamp(ts timestamp) returns varchar(20)
as
begin
    return extract(year from ts) || 
        '-' || lpad(extract(month from ts), 2, '0') || 
        '-' || lpad(extract(day from ts), 2, '0') || 
        'T' || lpad(extract(hour from ts), 2, '0') || 
        ':' || lpad(extract(minute from ts), 2, '0') || 
        ':' || lpad(extract(second from ts), 2, '0');
end
```

Note that I have left out the fractional seconds, as those will introduce additional headaches.

Answer (score 1):

This one is ugly but it works. I wish there was a built-in fuction for ISO8601 in Firebird.

```
substring(replace
                (replace
                       (replace
                         (cast(cast(TARGETDATE as timestamp) as varchar(24)
                        ), '-', '') 
                 , ' ', 'T')
           , ':', '') from 1 for 15) as TARGETDATE
```

Input: 2016.12.19, 14:07:56  -> Output: 20161219T140756

Comment: ISO-8601 is yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffff, not all non-separated. And unfortunately this solution will not always work correctly, as it depends on the underlying locale settings of the server.

Comment: thank you for your help. you are right it should be more like substring(replace(cast(cast(TARGETDATE as timestamp) as varchar(24)) , ' ', 'T') from 1 for 19) but your answer is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The [`EXTRACT`-function](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-functions-datetime.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-extract) with unit `second` will give you fractional seconds in Firebird 2.

```
extract(second from ts)
```

Leftpadding won't look beautiful. There will be a dot after the number if seconds < 10.
If you have Firebird 2.x and want to convert from Delphi style double precision timestamp, you can use this (you will have 4 digits after seconds, that's the most accurate I could get):

```
select 
extract(year from ts'1899-12-30 00:00' + T) ||'-' ||
lpad(extract(month from ts'1899-12-30 00:00' + T),2, '0') || '-' ||
lpad(extract(day from ts'1899-12-30 00:00' + T),2, '0') || 'T' ||
lpad(extract(hour from ts'1899-12-20 00:00' + T),2, '0') || ':' ||
lpad(extract(minute from ts'1899-12-20 00:00' + T),2, '0') || ':' ||
lpad(extract(second from ts'1899-12-20 00:00' + T),7, '0')
```

T is your Delphi style, double precision date column.